# How to retrieve list of encoded files and paths after a done job in MediaConvert?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

As stated in the title, nothing in their API seems to provide a list of encoded files after a job is complete, crucial in case of HLS encoding since I need to move them from S3 to another cloud provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaConvert emits CloudWatch Events [1]  for job status changes. You can implement this workflow by capturing jobs that go into a COMPLETE status and triggering a lambda function to gather required S3 paths. The COMPLETE CloudWatch event provide you the `playlistFilePaths` and `outputFilePaths` that will contain the S3 path your main and variant playlist.

CloudWatch event pattern to capture all completed jobs.

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.mediaconvert"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "status": [
      "COMPLETE"
    ]
  }
}
```

An example for the CloudWatch event payload can be found in the documentation [1]

== Resources == 
[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/apple-hls-group.html

Comment: It's almost the way, it does work with single encoded files, but not when there are multiple files in the output (HLS and other transcode), it's just outputting the main .m3u8 file

Comment: You can parse the path for outputFilePaths per each variant, and find the directory where all the segments live.

For example, you have a job that has the following:

Destination: s3://bucket/123/main 
Output 1: name modifier /1/v1 
Output 2: name modifier /2/v2 

Your outputDetails  would look like 


"outputFilePaths": [ "s3://bucket/123/main/1/v1.m3u8"],

"outputFilePaths": [ "s3://bucket/123/main/2/v2.m3u8" ], 


You could then just list keys for bucket/123/main/1/ and get all the segments for that variant. Repeat for the second outputFilePaths