# AWS Elemental MediaConvert CreateJob Example Using the AWS SDK for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-media-convert

I am trying to change the **Input Clipping StartTimecode and end timecode** of my **file input** and save the clipped video to **file output Destination in S3 bucket**

Currently, I am able to perform the operation using the below code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Amazon.MediaConvert;
 using Amazon.MediaConvert.Model;

namespace MediaConvertNET
{

class Program
{

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        String mediaConvertRole = "Your AWS Elemental MediaConvert role ARN";
        String fileInput = "s3://yourinputfile";
        String fileOutput = "s3://youroutputdestination";
        String mediaConvertEndpoint = "";

        // If we do not have our customer-specific endpoint
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mediaConvertEndpoint))
        {
            // Obtain the customer-specific MediaConvert endpoint
            AmazonMediaConvertClient client = new AmazonMediaConvertClient("AccessKey", "AccessSecret", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest1);
            DescribeEndpointsRequest describeRequest = new DescribeEndpointsRequest();

            DescribeEndpointsResponse describeResponse = await client.DescribeEndpointsAsync(describeRequest);
            mediaConvertEndpoint = describeResponse.Endpoints[0].Url;
        }

        // Since we have a service url for MediaConvert, we do not
        // need to set RegionEndpoint. If we do, the ServiceURL will
        // be overwritten
        AmazonMediaConvertConfig mcConfig = new AmazonMediaConvertConfig
        {
            ServiceURL = mediaConvertEndpoint,
        };

        AmazonMediaConvertClient mcClient = new AmazonMediaConvertClient("AccessKey", "AccessSecret", mcConfig);
        CreateJobRequest createJobRequest = new CreateJobRequest();

        createJobRequest.Role = mediaConvertRole;
        createJobRequest.UserMetadata.Add("Customer", "Amazon");

        #region Create job settings
        JobSettings jobSettings = new JobSettings();
        jobSettings.AdAvailOffset = 0;
        jobSettings.TimecodeConfig = new TimecodeConfig();
        jobSettings.TimecodeConfig.Source = TimecodeSource.EMBEDDED;
        createJobRequest.Settings = jobSettings;

        #region OutputGroup
        OutputGroup ofg = new OutputGroup();
        ofg.Name = "File Group";
        ofg.OutputGroupSettings = new OutputGroupSettings();
        ofg.OutputGroupSettings.Type = OutputGroupType.FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS;
        ofg.OutputGroupSettings.FileGroupSettings = new FileGroupSettings();
        ofg.OutputGroupSettings.FileGroupSettings.Destination = fileOutput;

        Output output = new Output();
        output.NameModifier = "_1";

        #region VideoDescription
        VideoDescription vdes = new VideoDescription();
        output.VideoDescription = vdes;
        vdes.ScalingBehavior = ScalingBehavior.DEFAULT;
        vdes.TimecodeInsertion = VideoTimecodeInsertion.DISABLED;
        vdes.AntiAlias = AntiAlias.ENABLED;
        vdes.Sharpness = 50;
        vdes.AfdSignaling = AfdSignaling.NONE;
        vdes.DropFrameTimecode = DropFrameTimecode.ENABLED;
        vdes.RespondToAfd = RespondToAfd.NONE;
        vdes.ColorMetadata = ColorMetadata.INSERT;
        vdes.CodecSettings = new VideoCodecSettings();
        vdes.CodecSettings.Codec = VideoCodec.H_264;
        H264Settings h264 = new H264Settings();
        h264.InterlaceMode = H264InterlaceMode.PROGRESSIVE;
        h264.NumberReferenceFrames = 3;
        h264.Syntax = H264Syntax.DEFAULT;
        h264.Softness = 0;
        h264.GopClosedCadence = 1;
        h264.GopSize = 90;
        h264.Slices = 1;
        h264.GopBReference = H264GopBReference.DISABLED;
        h264.SlowPal = H264SlowPal.DISABLED;
        h264.SpatialAdaptiveQuantization = H264SpatialAdaptiveQuantization.ENABLED;
        h264.TemporalAdaptiveQuantization = H264TemporalAdaptiveQuantization.ENABLED;
        h264.FlickerAdaptiveQuantization = H264FlickerAdaptiveQuantization.DISABLED;
        h264.EntropyEncoding = H264EntropyEncoding.CABAC;
        h264.Bitrate = 2000000;
        h264.FramerateControl = H264FramerateControl.SPECIFIED;
        h264.RateControlMode = H264RateControlMode.CBR;
        h264.CodecProfile = H264CodecProfile.MAIN;
        h264.Telecine = H264Telecine.NONE;
        h264.MinIInterval = 0;
        h264.AdaptiveQuantization = H264AdaptiveQuantization.HIGH;
        h264.CodecLevel = H264CodecLevel.AUTO;
        h264.FieldEncoding = H264FieldEncoding.PAFF;
        h264.SceneChangeDetect = H264SceneChangeDetect.ENABLED;
        h264.QualityTuningLevel = H264QualityTuningLevel.SINGLE_PASS;
        h264.FramerateConversionAlgorithm = H264FramerateConversionAlgorithm.DUPLICATE_DROP;
        h264.UnregisteredSeiTimecode = H264UnregisteredSeiTimecode.DISABLED;
        h264.GopSizeUnits = H264GopSizeUnits.FRAMES;
        h264.ParControl = H264ParControl.SPECIFIED;
        h264.NumberBFramesBetweenReferenceFrames = 2;
        h264.RepeatPps = H264RepeatPps.DISABLED;
        h264.FramerateNumerator = 30;
        h264.FramerateDenominator = 1;
        h264.ParNumerator = 1;
        h264.ParDenominator = 1;
        output.VideoDescription.CodecSettings.H264Settings = h264;
        #endregion VideoDescription

        #region AudioDescription
        AudioDescription ades = new AudioDescription();
        ades.LanguageCodeControl = AudioLanguageCodeControl.FOLLOW_INPUT;
        // This name matches one specified in the Inputs below
        ades.AudioSourceName = "Audio Selector 1";
        ades.CodecSettings = new AudioCodecSettings();
        ades.CodecSettings.Codec = AudioCodec.AAC;
        AacSettings aac = new AacSettings();
        aac.AudioDescriptionBroadcasterMix = AacAudioDescriptionBroadcasterMix.NORMAL;
        aac.RateControlMode = AacRateControlMode.CBR;
        aac.CodecProfile = AacCodecProfile.LC;
        aac.CodingMode = AacCodingMode.CODING_MODE_2_0;
        aac.RawFormat = AacRawFormat.NONE;
        aac.SampleRate = 48000;
        aac.Specification = AacSpecification.MPEG4;
        aac.Bitrate = 64000;
        ades.CodecSettings.AacSettings = aac;
        output.AudioDescriptions.Add(ades);
        #endregion AudioDescription

        #region Mp4 Container
        output.ContainerSettings = new ContainerSettings();
        output.ContainerSettings.Container = ContainerType.MP4;
        Mp4Settings mp4 = new Mp4Settings();
        mp4.CslgAtom = Mp4CslgAtom.INCLUDE;
        mp4.FreeSpaceBox = Mp4FreeSpaceBox.EXCLUDE;
        mp4.MoovPlacement = Mp4MoovPlacement.PROGRESSIVE_DOWNLOAD;
        output.ContainerSettings.Mp4Settings = mp4;
        #endregion Mp4 Container

        ofg.Outputs.Add(output);
        createJobRequest.Settings.OutputGroups.Add(ofg);
        #endregion OutputGroup

        #region Input
        Input input = new Input();

        InputClipping ip = new InputClipping();
        ip.StartTimecode= "00:00:00:00";
        ip.EndTimecode= "00:00:05:00";

        input.FilterEnable = InputFilterEnable.AUTO;
        input.PsiControl = InputPsiControl.USE_PSI;
        input.FilterStrength = 0;
        input.DeblockFilter = InputDeblockFilter.DISABLED;
        input.DenoiseFilter = InputDenoiseFilter.DISABLED;
        input.TimecodeSource = InputTimecodeSource.ZEROBASED;
        input.InputClippings.Add(ip);
        input.FileInput = fileInput;

        AudioSelector audsel = new AudioSelector();
        audsel.Offset = 0;
        audsel.DefaultSelection = AudioDefaultSelection.NOT_DEFAULT;
        audsel.ProgramSelection = 1;
        audsel.SelectorType = AudioSelectorType.TRACK;
        audsel.Tracks.Add(1);
        input.AudioSelectors.Add("Audio Selector 1", audsel);

        input.VideoSelector = new VideoSelector();
        input.VideoSelector.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.FOLLOW;

        createJobRequest.Settings.Inputs.Add(input);
        #endregion Input
        #endregion Create job settings

        try
        {
            CreateJobResponse createJobResponse =await mcClient.CreateJobAsync(createJobRequest);
            Console.WriteLine("Job Id: {0}", createJobResponse.Job.Id);
        }
        catch (BadRequestException bre)
        {
            // If the enpoint was bad
            if (bre.Message.StartsWith("You must use the customer-"))
            {
                // The exception contains the correct endpoint; extract it
                mediaConvertEndpoint = bre.Message.Split('\'')[1];
                // Code to retry query
            }
        }

    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Task.Run(() => MainAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

}

There are a couple of points which I wanted to know:

1. Is it mandatory to create VideoDescription Object and AudioDescription objects as I just wanted to
   perform only clipping operation

   ```
    InputClipping ip = new InputClipping();
    ip.StartTimecode= "00:00:00:00";
    ip.EndTimecode= "00:00:05:00";
   ```

2.**CreateJobResponse createJobResponse =await mcClient.CreateJobAsync(createJobRequest);**
How can I check my job process is completed or not

3. In case the job process is completed, in return how can I get the S3 bucket new output file created URL as I wanted to save that URL to my database.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1:
Depending on your workflow you output object must contain on the following descriptions combinations :

- VideoDescription & AudioDescription (video and audio muxed)
- VideoDescription (video only)
- AudioDescription (audio only)

This will insure your output has video only/video and audio/audio only.

MediaConvert will encode the input in the clipping region you define. The service do not pass video or audio through to the output (sometimes called transmuxing in the video community). Think of the output out of MediaConvert as a brand new file.

Question 2:
I would advise using CloudWatch Events to monitor job progression. See the following documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/how-mediaconvert-jobs-progress.html 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/cloudwatch_events.html

Question 3:
See my post in [How to retrieve list of encoded files and paths after a done job in MediaConvert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67380913/how-to-retrieve-list-of-encoded-files-and-paths-after-a-done-job-in-mediaconvert)

You can get this information by collecting the COMPLETE CloudWatch Event.